# Importing a project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Hi Iam facing some issue while cloning a project from Git.

Issue: While cloning a project I am using an option 'Check out from version control-->GitHub' and then am giving the git url and directory names.
For Project1 am getting the option.

Project1:
"Would you like to create an IDEA project for the sources you have checked out to D:\Users\myname\Pardirname\dirname?"

Project2:
For project2 am getting below option
"You have checked out an IDEA project file:
D:\Users\myname\Pardirname\dirname\build.sbt
Would you like to open it?"

For Project2 as soon as I select that option I will get an option 'Use auto import' which if I select it will import all the dependencies by itself.

But for project1 I don't see the 'Use auto import' option, I only see options like 'Create project from existing sources' or 'Import project from existing model'.

What could be the issue with the project1, can any one please assist me ?

Answer (score 1):

Project2 sources already include IDEA project configuration files, which are saved in `.idea` subfolder in the project root. When you check it out, IDEA detects the folder and acts accordingly.

Seems there is no .idea folder in the Project1, only sources, thus IDEA offers you to create a new project.

BTW, it should find all frameworks and modules during the **Create project** wizard.